# Missing Qrefine function?

Tags: r

I keep getting the error message
could not find function "Qrefine".

Got the error message when I keyed in the following in RStudio. Could someone help, please?

```
Qrefine.out <- Qrefine(data, Q_mis, gate="AND", max.ite=50)
print(Qrefine.out)
plot(Qrefine.out)
```

Comment: Did you start with `library(NPCD)` ?

Comment: Thanks! That solved the issue I was facing. I'm new to R. Would I always need to specify the library before beginning analysis?

Comment: Yes, you need to load the library (package) which provides the function if that library is not loaded by default. In RStudio, loaded packages are indicated in the Packages pane. Otherwise `(.packages())` lists loaded packages.

Comment: Yes.  There are a small number of libraries that are automatically loaded, but  most aren't.  Each time that you use them,  you must load them with the `library()` function.   To see what libraries are loaded at any given time,   type `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Thanks for the comments and help. They were really useful!